# If I install Windows 7 on another harddrive on my PC will the Windows 10 bootloader be replaced?

Tags: windows-7, bootloader

If I install Windows 7 on another harddrive on my PC will the Windows 10 bootloader be replaced?!

I relly need to know.

Comment: This is actually somewhat complicated. Windows 10 only supports EFI booting, but Windows 7, as I recall, supports the older BIOS boot loading process *and* EFI. You will want to make sure that you use (U)EFI booting to boot the Windows 7 install CD... then the installation will default to EFI as well. As to whether or not Windows 7 will play nice with the existing Windows 10 install... that's actually one of the design goals of EFI. So it *should* but I can't say for sure that it **will**.

Answer (score -1):

It shouldn't be replaced, but windows 10 will still force itself to be booted first.  You can change this behavior by changing the order in  Control Panel > System > Advanced System Settings under startup and recovery.  Here you can change the order in which drives are booted from the bootloader's perspective.